# What are examples of successful novel ecosystem integration?

Tags: ecosystem, climate-change

The cultivation of novel ecosystems, while formerly disparaged due to being conceptually misappropriated by special interest groups, may be necessary in adapting to climate change or simply in innovating more sustainable farming practices.

What are successful contemporary examples of novel ecosystem development?

Comment: Could you share some sort of definition of a novel ecosystem? I assume you are not talking about pathological invasions or sub-pathological species introduction, as those are quite common, or e.g. Galapagos-style patchwork ecosystems made from periodic introductions. Can you link to some sort of resource explaining what exactly you mean? What time-scale, how many species, is it on top of an existing ecosystem?

Comment: It's quite possible I am referring to exactly what you suggest, though not limited to that example. I am referring to a certain circumstances wherein a new ecosystem emerges on its own as a result of climate change and possibly nonnative species which happen to either intentionally or unintentionally introduced while present in the process. I can't really be specific because the thing you are asking me for is what I am asking others for. It's just a theoretical concept but at this point in climate change it must be happening somewhere.

Comment: It might help if you could provide a few links (e.g. an example of "disparage[ment] due to being conceptually misappropriated by special interest groups"); I'm not skeptical of your claim, but I'm a little unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not 100% sure of what the intent is here, but I think that you should look into [community assembly rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_rules). The basic (not universally or even generally accepted) idea is that there is some set of "rules" that makes a "successful" or stable ecological community. You can use those rules to design communities accordingly, goes the logic. [Here is a short blog post](https://greatecology.com/2013/10/04/ecological-assembly-rules/) that has some handy refs and simple language.

You could also look into microcosm + mesocosm research, where people have designed small self-sufficient communities, [sometimes sealed off from e.g. gas exchange with the outside environments](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867412005156). Sometimes these collapse, and sometimes they work. Occasionally it has to do with randomness, and at other points it seems to follow a deterministic path.

All of these are under the heading of "[community ecology](https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/biodiversity-and-ecosystem-stability-17059965)", which I would strongly recommend looking into if you are interested.

I would also strongly recommend looking into invasion research, which is the most prominent example of getting a "new" community by just adding a few species to an existing community and seeing what happens. As I suggested in the comments, looking at communities on islands that have been invaded or have recruited species from elsewhere could be handy- e.g. Galapagos, Oceania, are examples to look into, how they have dealt with biological invasions and what has worked and what hasn't. This subfield is called "[island biogeography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insular_biogeography#:%7E:text=Insular%20biogeography%20or%20island%20biogeography,relationship%20occurring%20in%20oceanic%20islands.)", I do not know how many people still take it seriously but there are at least a lot of empirical observations about what happens when you add species.

Comment: Thank you for this more general information, I'll look into it.